# Flink keep not running on localhost

Tags: rest, localhost, apache-flink

I want to restrict Flink's rest api to be accessible from everywhere so I changed `flink-conf.yaml` file as following:

```
#==============================================================================
# Rest & web frontend
#==============================================================================

# The port to which the REST client connects to. If rest.bind-port has
# not been specified, then the server will bind to this port as well.
#
rest.port: 8081

# The address to which the REST client will connect to
#
rest.address: 127.0.0.1
```

However, `netstat -ln | grep 8081` tells me that it still running on `0.0.0.0:8081`

any ideas on this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment out this line `rest.address: 127.0.0.1` and type `rest.bind-address: 127.0.0.1` instead